# How do I change my CognitoIdentityCredentials by cognito access token

Tags: amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I'm implementing a custom UI using AWS Amplify Federated Identities(Facebook and Google) but after the authorization from these providers I'm receiving an CognitoIdentityCredentials. How can I change it by an congnito AccessToken?

Comment: OK, I guess we can do it using Hosted UI. I'll check and let you guys know. Take a look at this thread https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/1073